# How to handwrite with onscreen samsung keyboard on vim?

Tags: input-methods

I am using J6+ samsung hp. I can handwritte with samsung onscreen keyboard on all social media platforms, but on vim I can't. Why not? Is there a workaround?

I need to write certain asian words that I don't know how to type. I do know how to write them, so I can follow the strokes to write it out, but the "T" button is disabled; this is what I normally click to do handwriting.

Is vim the problem here?

Comment: This is an Android device, correct? Are you using DroidVim? Or something different? Where is your Vim coming from in this device?

Comment: Yes, Android device, samsung J6+ handphone.  Yes using Droidvim.  I don't understand your question "where is your vim coming from in this device?" I can only suspect this is droidvim issue.. Because i can use samsung handwritting on all software that i know on my phone. Somehow when in vim, the "handwritting" button just not clickable. Any Idea ?  I like vim , it is super powerful.. although i know i just used a small "edge" of it potential

Comment: All i can do right now is to do hand writting on other text software; copy it and paste into vim.

Comment: Try going to "Menu" and enable "One-line text box" and try to enter your text there. My understanding is that this text box is supposed to allow you to use the phone/tablet native input, so maybe it will allow you to use the handwriting mode. There's also "Preferences" -> "Text input mode" with quite a few settings (such as modes for "Direct input" or "Normal input"), maybe try tweaking those to see if they'll help.

Comment: Thanks @filbranden both of your suggested method works. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 2:
"One-line text box" and try to enter your text there.

Method 1:
"Preferences" -> "Text input mode" --> "Direct input" or "Normal input"

Thanks to Fillbranden.